# Synchronous or Asynchronous requests in iPhone SDK

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, asynchronous, synchronous

Can anyone help is below request is Synchronous or Asynchronous requests?

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sampleRequest.com/request`enter code here`"];
        NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        [tempElement setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` method triggers a *synchronous* request, as it returns the data of that request. This is only possible with a synchronous request which blocks your thread until the request is done.

If you want an asynchronous request, look into [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Specifically, you want [+[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest%3adelegate%3a). You'll need to implement a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Look into the [Using NSURLConnection guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).